# Check parent view name of nested view in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I find the view in SQL Server which is nested under different views, so I want to check all the parent views who nest this view in SQL Server .

For example, I have a nested view `nested_abc` and it is nested under `parent_view1`, `parent_view2`, etc. I want to find how many views are using or nesting this `nested_abc` view.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to do this would be to use SSMS. As an example, I created these two views in a test database:

```
CREATE VIEW Test_View_1
AS
SELECT 1 as val

GO

CREATE VIEW Test_View_2
AS
SELECT *
FROM Test_View_1
GO
```

When these were created, I right-clicked `Test_View_1`, and selected the popup menu option **View Dependencies**. This gave me the following window:

[image]

As you can see, it shows that the view Test_View_2 is dependent on Test_View_1. Do the same thing with your view (right click, select view dependencies) and you can see what other code is dependent on that view.

Comment: Thanks alot for answering in detail. perfect solution.  :)