# T-SQL :: Enumerate all nested views

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, view, nested

I have a database in my hands that is in very bad shape.

With horror I discovered that there are nested views (a view that call another view).

Thanks to [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57961019/check-parent-view-name-of-nested-view-in-sql-server) I know how to see if a view had dependencies from the SSMS GUI. Is there a way I can query the whole database and enumerate all the nested views?

Comment: Have a look at [`sys.sql_expression_dependencies`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-sql-expression-dependencies-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). A couple of joins with [`sys.views`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-views-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) should do it.

Comment: Why with horror?  object reuse is a Good thing...

Comment: Thank you @xQbert, I find on every blog that is bad practice. Do you have another opinion?

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/151169/are-views-harmful-for-performance-in-postgresql  They are fine when used appropriately.  It's when views get reused without evaluating the underlying purpose and ensuring the work being done is needed; or get overloaded is when you start to run into problems.   They work great in small -reusable components that contain necessary business logic.  That way the logic is in ONE reusalbe place and all other places needing that logic can leverage it.  That way if logic changes, it changes in once place not all over the place.  But this is off topic ...

Comment: Also: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5487/is-nested-view-a-good-database-design  By themselves they are not good or bad;  it's how they get used that causes that.    If the horror is that there's lots of tables being joined that aren't needed causing performance problems then yes that is a bad implementation; but if the views are built so business rule are in one place, and each view is specific in it's purpose and pulled together using good reuse with minimal impact to performance; then awesome!  Maintenance just go easier!  No silver bullet, not broad brush. each on it's own merits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this gets you close to what you are looking for.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    sd.object_id,
    referencing_view_name = OBJECT_NAME(sd.object_id),
    sd.referenced_major_id,
    referenced_view_name = OBJECT_NAME(sd.referenced_major_id)
FROM
    sys.sql_dependencies sd
WHERE 
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.views v WHERE sd.object_id = v.object_id)
    AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.views v WHERE sd.referenced_major_id = v.object_id);
```

**EDIT**: Same info as the original but using **sys.sql_expression_dependencies** in place of **sys.sql_dependencies**

```
SELECT 
    sed.referencing_id,
    referencing_view_name = OBJECT_NAME(sed.referencing_id),    
    sed.referenced_id,
    referenced_view_name = sed.referenced_entity_name
FROM
    sys.sql_expression_dependencies sed
WHERE 
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.views v WHERE sed.referencing_id = v.object_id)
    AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.views v WHERE sed.referenced_id = v.object_id);
```

Comment: From [`sys.sql_dependencies`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-sql-dependencies-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15): "**Important** - This feature will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server. Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use this feature. Use `sys.sql_expression_dependencies` instead."

Comment: Good info. Thank you.

Comment: @HABO updated to include an alternate version using sys.sql_expression_dependencies

Comment: Thank you @JasonA.Long, today you teach me how to use `EXISTS`

Answer (score -1):

The following query uses the non-deprecated system view `sys.sql_expression_dependencies` to get the names of views referenced by views:

```
select Ving.name as ReferencingViewName, Ved.name as ReferencedViewName
  from sys.sql_expression_dependencies as SED inner join
    sys.views as Ving on Ving.object_id = SED.referencing_id inner join
    sys.views as Ved on Ved.object_id = SED.referenced_id;
```

Comment: Thank you @HABO, your `INNER JOIN` is less expensive